# Overriding default foreign key and local key in Eloquent relationships Laravel 5

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am confused about second and third arguments while defining eloquent relationships.

```
public function phone()
    {
return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');
}
```

I understand the second argument in both relationships, it is foreign key which will be same. However, I am confused about third argument about what it refers to? I have an assumption that this is the key to which foreign key refers so it would be same too in both relationships. I do not know whether I am right or wrong. Please elaborate the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.

Both arguments refer to the exact same two columns.

Both `foreign_key` parameters are the foreign key column on the `phone` table.
*(Without specifying anything that would be `user_id` in your case)*

`local_key` and `other_key` are the counterpart, the column the foreign key points to.
In most cases that's also the primary key column of the other table.
*(Without specifying anything that would be `id` in your case)*